# meaning of "Adamic ecstasy of naming"

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> The belief that the art of the novel can be discussed and evaluated only after its narrative techniques or "devices" have been identified and enumerated launches novel theory into an **Adamic ecstasy of naming.**

I have no idea what this phrase really mean.

Comment: Feasibly it's a typo / malapropism for ***academic***, but I seem to recall that in the Bible there's reference to Adam (and Eve?) going through an extended process of ***assigning names*** to each different species of animal and plant that God has provided for them to have dominion over. [***Adamic***](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/2087?redirectedFrom=Adamic#eid) = *Of, belonging to, or characteristic of Adam; resembling Adam in nature or condition*, in the full OED.

Comment: What does "naming" mean?What does "naming" refer to?

Comment: As highlighted above, and again here - ***naming** = **assigning names***. Same as *The teacher is marking our homework*, where ***marking** = **assigning marks** (scores, ratings)*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers it is nothing to do with "academic" please delete your comment. Or put it in an answer.

Comment: @JamesK: Don't be silly! The thrust of my comment makes it quite clear I *don't* think it's a typo or a malapropism! I didn't post an answer because to a considerable extent this looks like something you can just look up in a dictionary, so long as you have a fairly detailed knowledge of Judeo-Christian mythology (which not all learners do). I withheld my VTC partly because I wasn't sure how obvious the relevant "Adamic attribute" would be to all nns, given that the first online dictionary I checked only explicitly mentioned ***Adamic earth**,* as a reference to "red clay".

Answer (score 4):

Adam was the "first" man in the bible. Adamic means is an adjective meaning "related to Adam".

In the bible, Adam names all the animals in the world. Then "ecstasy" literally means "coming out of yourself", but it often means a trace-like state of extreme pleasure. An "ecstasy of naming" is a figurative expression meaning something like "such excessive naming of things that you enter a trance".

The idea here is that if you think that each narrative device needs a name, you will need to be like Adam and have to name thousands of narrative devices.  (It is implied that you do not need to name every narrative device to have a useful discussion of novel theory)

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that the "ecstasy" that Adam experienced was the absolute power of being the first to name a thing.

Think about the immense power of being able to name a thing -- such as a newly discovered species, a new star or planet, etc.  There's a certain power and majesty to being "first," at least for Western man, who strives to conquer the universe.  Conquerors name things.  Adam had dominion over all the creatures of the Earth; in a way, he was a conqueror.

The meaning of the reference is that, when a reader of a novel or other text has complete freedom to invent a narrative or "subtext" in order to deconstruct or analyze the work he is reading, he has the same kind of absolute, unchallenged power over the text and its "meaning" that Adam had when he named the creatures of the Earth.  The "techniques" or "devices" enumerated and named by the reader-*qua*-analyst need not be known, intended or even comprehensible to the author of the text.  This is where the "absolute power" comes in; no permission or agreement from the author is needed.

The "naming" that the analyst performs is the naming (identifying) of hidden devices in the text.  In other words: the author doesn't know what he meant, or what made him write what he did.  But the analyst is smarter; he can see the "devices" and point them out for the edification of the rest of us.

This methodology of interpreting texts according to some extra-textual (or sub-textual) "meaning" gives the analyst or reader absolute power, since he is constrained only by his imagination.  There are no rules, nothing has to make sense or cohere, it only has to be an acceptable "narrative" -- which means, it needs to be politically and aesthetically acceptable to the audience.  And of course, the analyst should be (or at least, *appear* to be) sincere.

This technique is what I would call "postmodernist," and the same characteristics that give it this "power" (arbitrariness, esotericism, subjectivism)  also make it meaningless and wholly subjective.  When any interpretation or "device" at all can be valid and meaningful, they are in fact all invalid and meaningless.  (Postmodernist practitioners will disagree with this assertion, but you should ignore them; they are charlatans and sophists.)

I don't know where you got the quote, but I'd guess it was written by a postmodernist practitioner (i.e., an academic, probably a professor who can force students to buy his books and read them.)  They traffic in gobbledygook, because they are confused nihilists, and you can do better if you are actually trying to make sense of a text.  But anyway, that's my take.